# WPF Datagrid Databind to class with static properties and dictionary containing dynamic property value entries

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, propertydescriptor, icustomtypedescriptor

UPDATED

I am updating this post because I did some more reading and decided to re-implement my solution.

Original Problem: I have a class with static properties and one Property that is a dynamic collection of properties (via a dictionary).  I want to databind my class to a wpf datagrid where each static property should be a column and each dictionary entry should be a column in the grid.

After doing some more research, I decided to implement a PropertyBag class that will contain my Dictionary of properties and values. Almost everything is working now.  I have my grid being displayed with all the correct columns and the static property values are being applied correctly.

However, now I am not able to get any of the values from the dictionary to be applied to the grid, and I am not sure where to go from here.

More info:

My database has 3 tables, a plate, a category, and a categoryplateassociation table.  Each plate can have 0 to many categories.  For now, I am populating each plate with all the categories and setting the strings to empty.  Then, when an association is returned (between a plate and category), I am setting the real value on the specific category name.  This all happens before the grid is created.

Property Bag:

```
public class PropertyBag
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get 
        {
            string value;
            values.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) values.Remove(key);
            else values[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Revised Plate class

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(PlateTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class Plate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID;
    private string name;
    private string status;
    private string creator;
    private Uri location;
    private string description;

    public Plate()
    {
        CustomCategories = new PropertyBag();
    }

    public PropertyBag CustomCategories { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;}
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    public string Creator
    {
        get { return creator; }
        set
        {
            creator = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Creator");
        }
    }

    public Uri Location
    {
        get { return location; }
        set
        {
            location = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public static Plate ConvertDataPlateToBusinessPlate(TestPlate dataPlate)
    {
        var plate = new Plate
                        {
                            Name = dataPlate.Name, 
                            Status = dataPlate.Status,
                            Creator = dataPlate.Creator, 
                            Description = dataPlate.Description, 
                            Location = new Uri(dataPlate.Location)
                        };
        return plate;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Revised CustomTypeDescriptor:

```
public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return GetProperties(null);
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = new ArrayList();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in base.GetProperties(attributes))
        {
            if(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(PropertyBag)))
            {
                //Static list of all category names
                var categoryNames = Categories.GetAll();
                foreach (var categoryName in categoryNames)
                {
                    properties.Add(new PropertyBagPropertyDescriptor(categoryName));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                properties.Add(propertyDescriptor);
            }

        }
        var props = (PropertyDescriptor[])properties.ToArray(typeof(PropertyDescriptor));
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props);
    }
```

Revised PropertyDescriptor

```
    public class PropertyBagPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    public PropertyBagPropertyDescriptor(string name) : base(name, null)
    {}

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return ((PropertyBag) component)[Name];
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        ((PropertyBag)component)[Name] = null;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        ((PropertyBag) component)[Name] = (string) value;
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return ((PropertyBag)component)[Name] != null;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return typeof(PropertyBag); }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(string); }
    }
}
```

simple ViewModel

```
 public TestPlateAdministratorViewModel()
    {
        CommandAggregator = new TestPlateAdministratorCommandAggregator(this);
        LoadData();
    }

    public static TestPlateAdministratorCommandAggregator CommandAggregator { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Plate> TestPlates{ get; set; }

    private static void LoadData()
    {
        CommandAggregator.LoadPlatesCommand.Execute(null);
        CommandAggregator.LoadCategoriesCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you bind a plate object or a collection of plate objects to the datagrid? And how should your datagrid look like, what should be shown? btw i really dont know why you use a PropertyDescriptor.

Comment: I bind an ObservableCollection<Plate> to the datagrid.  I am using a PropertyDescriptor as a way of manipulating what properties are being displayed in the grid.  This is the part I cannot get to work.  I want to set each entry in the Dictionary as a Property of plate where the name is the property name and the value is the property value.  Am I going in the wrong direction with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your Dictionary in your PropertyBag has a fixed size or does the keys are known?

you did not post your xaml for your datagrid, but the binding from the propertybag to one column could look like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Col4TestKey" Binding="{Binding CustomCategories[test]}"/>
```

i really dont know wether your PropertyBag setter will work with binding. all in all this just would work if you have a know set of keys for your dictionary.

btw, i use flat datatables in my projects for such dynamic stuff, there are really easy to handle.

Comment: I will not know the set of category names (the keys to my dictionary) until run time when they are loaded from the database.  The user has the ability to add and remove categories from the database, so there is no way for me to hard code category names.  But, you are correct, if I knew the names in advance this would be a simple issue to solve.